# Unable to properly consume SharePoint data

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, csom

I've been unsuccessfully trying to make my application consume SharePoint data.

I followed these steps from c-sharpcorner.com https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consume-sharepoint-online-csom-rest-api-with-dotnet-core-3-1/

the only difference is the permissions I've set in the registered application like this:
[image]

AllSites.Read doesnt have the status granted, but since it says "Admin consent required: No", I didnt bother, not sure if that's causing the issue.

So, the issue:
I've been trying to retrieve a specific list from the SharePoint. With the same user I used to register the required application on Azure AD, I can access this list directly through the web browser, I can even see a XML file with all lists of this subsite if I access https://MyCompanys.sharepoint.com/sites/Site/SubSite/_api/lists

However, through my code I see 0 lists.

```
        string user = "TheUser@user.com";
        string password = "password";

        Uri site = new Uri("https://MyCompanys.sharepoint.com/sites/Site/SubSite/");

        SecureString securedPassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            securedPassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager())
        using (var context = authenticationManager.GetContext(site, user, securedPassword))
        {
            context.Load(context.Web.Lists);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            var lists = context.Web.Lists;
        }
```

[image]

When I try to access a specific list by name or id I receive an 'Access is denied' exception.

[image]

What did I do wrong? am I missing another permission here?

Answer (score 0):

To access specific list you need `AllSites.Manage` delegated API permission.

Try to also load `site` and `web` before loading `list` if it works.

```
var mySite = context.Site;
context.Load(mySite);
var web = context.Web;
context.Load(web);
var lists = context.Web.Lists;
context.Load(lists);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on my research and testing, if you want to retrieve a specific list, you can use the following code (**Note**: You need to have `AllSites.Read` permissions)：

```
List targetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name");
```

In addition, if you want to update or delete a specific list, `AllSites.FullControl` permission is required.

More information for reference: [SharePoint CSOM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to retrieve a specific list from the SharePoint site, I will recommend to use the `Sites.Selected` permissions.

`Sites.Selected` permissions allows you to set the specific site collections and access level you want to grant to individual applications.

Read more information about this in below articles:

1. [Controlling app access on a specific SharePoint site collections is now available](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/)
2. [Sites.Selected for SharePoint CSOM / REST](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/updates-on-controlling-app-specific-access-on-specific-sharepoint-sites-sites-selected/)